# Add value to a variable even if it doesn't exist

Tags: php

`$_SESSION['val'] += 9;`

If `$_SESSION['val']` is not initialized, it'll throw a notice that `$_SESSION['val']` is not defined.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['val'])) 
    $_SESSION['val'] = 9; 
else $_SESSION['val'] += 9;
```

Is there a way to simplify this in PHP ? (PHP 7)

Comment: I was hoping to use the ?? operator

Comment: Have you tried Ternary operator?